# Ethernet problem. New to linux and about to cry

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet, tethering

So today i installed Ubuntu to start learning about web development and it all went well till i finally started Ubuntu and to my surprise my computer did not see the Ethernet connection. I have windows 10 installed on another partition and it uses the Ethernet connection without any problems so it can't be the fault of the cable or the router. Ubuntu can use internet via tethering from my phone and it would probably be able to use WiFi if my PC was able to use it, but for some reason it has problems with seeing the Ethernet connection. Please help i will provide all the info you guys need to help me.

lshw -C network

```
    *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df200000-df21ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20f0u6
       serial: c2:dd:3d:cc:86:18
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.17 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe e1000e` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: For most of my day i was using ubuntu 18.04.1 but an minute ago i installed 18.10 but the problem didn't go away

Comment: also the terminal comman `sudo modprobe e1000e` does nothing

Comment: It looks like you installed an old ndis driver (rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005) that's causing your problem. Do you remember installing this? Also, show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this a server? What make/model computer?

Comment: Don't install a different operating system to learn web development. Focus on web development. Learn Linux learn Ubuntu, but if that's your end game goal, learn web development using whatever environment you're already using. It's like learning another speaking language so you can learn how to bake a cake. Even if a lot of people in the kitchen already know how to speak that other language, it's just really not necessary and will get in the way. Try using Windows Subsystem for Linux if you really insist.

Comment: @heynnema The second network has no problems as you can see. It's the internet on my phone via tethering. The drivers are for that. It works and you should not be focusing on that.

Comment: @JoshuaK Thanks for your advice but it's completly wrong. I am not learning how to use linux. I would only need it for parts of the course i am using. It's not like i want to learn everything there is about linux. Also i just asked how to deal with one i would guess simple problem.

Comment: After you loaded the driver with modprobe, did the device create an interface; something like enp0s25 or eno1 or some such? Check: `ip addr show` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @Solarka still worth trying in WSL.